# Array TextView click to Call Phone Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, textview

I am working on a mobile app for my bachelor degree and I am trying to insert a new functionality, when someone click on the number in the textview to call that number. I wrote the code below, and I was expecting to work fine but I get an error. There is one textview that hold the phone number, but there is more than one person with phone number. I think that if it was only one person with a phone number it woulb be fine.

**This how the list of phone number looks like - all in textView3**

PhoneNUmber1 (textView3)

PhoneNUmber2 (textView3)

PhoneNUmber3 (textView3)

and so on

**The error :**

```
06-28 13:48:49.574 I/MonoDroid(30648): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
06-28 13:48:49.584 I/MonoDroid(30648): System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

**The code in the MainActivy in OnCreate function is**

```
 TextView txtViewTel = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView3);

    string stringtelefon = txtViewTel.ToString();

//          Toast.MakeText(this, stringtelefon, ToastLength.Short).Show();



    txtViewTel.Click += delegate
    {
      var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(stringtelefon);
      var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionDial, uri);
      StartActivity(intent);
    };
```

textView3 is a text view that has phone numbers for each client in a array.

**The AXML is**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:background="#F1F1F1">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgPic"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_client"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#3B5998"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:layoutDirection="inherit" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="65">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:text="Nume Client"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="65"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#000" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:text="Prenume Client"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="65"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#000" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:text="Telefon"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="65"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:layout_marginRight="1.3dp"
            android:clickable="true" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/btnStar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:button="@android:drawable/btn_star"
        android:checked="false" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Adding Phone numbers in View - TextView**

```
 public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View row = convertView;

            if (row == null)
            {
                row = LayoutInflater.From(mContext).Inflate(mLayout, parent, false);
            }

            row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1).Text = mClient[position].NumeClient;
            row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView2).Text = mClient[position].PrenumeClient;
            row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView3).Text = mClient[position].TelClient;

            ImageView pic = row.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imgPic);

            if (mClient[position].Image != null)
            {
                pic.SetImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(mClient[position].Image, 0, mClient[position].Image.Length));
            }

            pic.Tag = position;
            pic.Click -= pic_Click;
            pic.Click += pic_Click;

            return row;
        }
```

**Deserialize JSON with data from database to populate the ListView**

```
private void webClient_DownloadDataCompleted(object sender, DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            RunOnUiThread(() =>
            {
                string json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Result);
          List<Client> mClient = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Client>>(json);
                Action<ImageView> action = PicSelected;
                mAdapter = new ClientiListAdapter(this, Resource.Layout.ListaClienti, mClient, action);
                mListView.Adapter = mAdapter;
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

For the telephone intent to work it has to be like so:

```
Uri.parse("tel:" + stringtelefon)
```

If that doesnt work then I might need to know abit more about the app:

Also are you using the layout in the xaml in a list view?

Where does the exception get called from, it should say the line number?

What is the format of the telephone numbers that you populate the textViews with?

Comment: The format of the telephone numbers is JSON. I populate a ListView with the data from the json ("FirstName","LastName","TelephoneNumber") . I've added the other code for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

For Android Xamarin

**RunOnUiThread(() => mylabel.Text = "Updated from other thread");**

Happy Coding :-)